# Ag-Grid - Column Filter not showing new values

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

The values in the column filter show properly the first time being opened. Issue comes from the second time onward after adding or deleting the values, filter values in the box are not refreshed (see screenshot below).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I found that if you run the following function it will give mostly the desired result. I am running this on any change event for the given column.

```
var filterInstance = gridApi.getFilterInstance('yourColumn');
filterInstance.resetFilterValues()
```

The bug still needs to be fixed by ag-grid, but this is a decent workaround. It would be good to add some logic to maintain any existing filter selections, but for the time being it fits my purposes. If anyone has a better approach, do let me know. :)